# Communicating the price on a single service, single price website

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, pricing

Having a pricing page or section that follows conventional pricing table design patterns seems to be a best practice for websites offering different services.

If a website offers only a single service for a single price, there is no need to compare different services and prices. The homepage could describe the service and show the price somewhere (e.g. price sticker).

Would such an approach have any drawbacks? In other words, would it be useful to have a separate, conventional pricing page/section even if the website offers only a single service at a single price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Would it be useful to have a separate pricing page / section for a single priced service?

A multi plan-price page has as its main purpose to be able to make a comparison of the functionalities included in each plan. In a single price service, such a comparison doesn't exist, so it's necessary to establish a reason for there to be an exclusive information page: the **single price advantages**.

- All the content in functionalities offered by the single price
- The single price offers the possibility of eliminating extra assets such as advertising, as it happens in online radios
- The single price allows access to all the content of the web, for example in subscriptions to online publications where part of the content is hidden.
- The single price offers third advantages unrelated to the content of the web, such as offers in the purchase of related products
- A single basic price allows access to the content of the web, but can also offer a custom plan through direct contact
- A free website with limited options offers a single price for a total service. For example, a page allows you to apply a filter to an image in low resolution and offers a single price with examples for high resolution ones.

In other words, if the single price doesn't have extra content to explain its reason or any comparative element about the advantages, it doesn't make sense that it exists as a separate section: *– if you have nothing good to say then remain silent –.*

Here an example, the single price page from [stripe.com](https://stripe.com/pricing):

[image]